# Building an app+backend with extraneous functionality for an existing web shop. How to handle authentication on the backend?

Tags: architecture, web-applications, authentication, backend, jwt

This is an architecture question as I've been asked by an existing web store to build a

- mobile app (they don't have a mobile app) that provides extra functionality to the store,
- a web admin panel to manage the app's content

The mobile app is to provide extra functionality (tracking orders, contests, rewards etc.) to the store, but it **will not have shopping capability**, i.e. users will not be able to view all products and place orders through the app.

So far it seems I need:

- a mobile app
- a backend app (API and business logic for the mobile app/web panel)
- a frontend for the admin panel
- a DB

I thought I'd set up a new DB for the project, but it poses a few problems.

First, the users should be able to log in. Users who already have accounts in the store, should be able to log into the app using the same credentials.

That means that my backend has to somehow authenticate the user with the store. The store uses cookies for authentication and doesn't appear to expose an API endpoint for verifying user credentials, but it can expose privileged API to get any customer's data, including its password hash (calculated by taking md5 of user password + hardcoded COOKIE_KEY value).

So what I can do on my backend, it to keep a local copy of this COOKIE_KEY value. When a mobile client tries to log in, I can then calculate the md5 hash and compare it with the hash that the store returns to me. If it matches, I'll issue a JWT token to the client. Like the following:

[image: authentication process]

Is this a good approach to the problem? I'm sure it's an easy one for a more experienced dev.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to improve the shop itself to act as the authenticator and plug that gaping md5 security vulnerability?

Comment: Hi and welcome. The question's title doesn't seem to fit the situation you're describing.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Thanks for pointing it out. Originally I thought I maybe had to use the same DB as the shop and migrate the schema to suit my needs, but as I was writing I realised that it's not a viable approach and forgot to change the title.

Comment: @Kain0_0 so you're suggesting to just try to add an endpoint to the shop that returns true if a password is valid for a particular user? 

How much of a vulnerability is the approach that I described?

Comment: I think md5 return data is quiet problematic, because if you have the hash, that mean in some ways it's same as you have the 'password', It's alright to have an endpoint as middleware to act as autheticator, but I really think it should be created on the online store endpoint, returning md5 is not good, and if the online store doesn't use ssl, then it mean anyone can sniff it, and they can create a return somehow to the app by spoofing in the middle(although you use jwt), but what if the app have a vurnebility, I think that created a complicated environment. TLDR, just add endpoint on store

Comment: I would have the shop return a token. Containing some random nonsense stored against the user, a sunset date (expirey), a set of priveleges, encrypted using a symetric key, then apply a cryptographic signature over the encrypted token. There are other schemes out there, find one that is cryptographically current. Your service can then verify the token validity by checking the signature, performing the decryption, and checking the permissions. If its really sensitive the nonsense can be checked against the shop to determine if its valid, and give your backend access to the user id.

Comment: @Kain0_0 Thank you! That's a lot of useful information to dig into.